Is Java stream filter smart enough to ignore unnecessary items in an ordered stream?
Let's say I have the following:
List<Integer> orderedList = Stream.of(5, 4, 0, 2, 1).sorted().toList();

If I apply a filter such as
List<Integer> filteredList = orderedList.stream().filter(integer -> integer < 3).toList();

Will filter check all items in orderedList, or given that it's ordered, it will stop filtering after it reaches the first false condition, i.e., integer >= 3, or does it always check all items?
If it checks all items, is there a smarter way to filter items in a situation with an ordered list?

that is the reason for having takeWhile()

In your scenario, since you return a list with all the elements matching the filter, filter() is applied for all the elements in the stream.
If you want to stop processing when a specific condition is true/false you can use takeWhile() from Java 9:
orderedList.stream().takeWhile(v -> v < 3).forEach(System.out::println);


Maybe note that takeWhile was added in Java 9 since there seem to be a lot of people still on Java 8

"Is there a smarter way to filter items in a situation with an ordered list?"
It depends on what you mean by smarter.  You could just use an imperative solution with a loop and not use streams.  Or if your ordered list is not immutable you could do the following:
list.removeIf(i->i >= 3);

If efficiency is the goal, note that there is no guarantee that post processing a sorted list is more efficient since to first sort the list is O(nLogn) and then you have possibly O(n) checks to filter the list where n is the size of the list. If the list wasn't sorted you could filter first and then sort the filtered list instead.
If takeWhile is not an option you could also find the index of the first item of your ordered list that satisfies the conditional. And then use that to grab a sublist.  The following presumes the list is sorted in ascending order.  The conditional test >= 3 is required to find the first index that is not to be part of your filteredList.
int index = IntStream.range(0, orderedList.size())
        .filter(i -> orderedList.get(i) >= 3).findFirst().orElse(orderedList.size());

List<Integer> filteredList = orderedList.subList(0, index);

Note: A sublist is a view of part of the original list.  Modifying the items in either list from 0 to index-1 inclusive will be reflected in the other.

It should be .orElse(orderedList.size()) But you can avoid the O(n) checks by using int index = Collections.binarySearch(orderedList, 3); List<Integer> filteredList = orderedList.subList(0, index < 0? ~index: index);
